# Control GPIO pins using USB

Tags: usb, adc, integrated-circuit, gpio, usb-host

What is the easiest way to make a device that can control GPIO pins using USB?

Can I make a device similar to [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264) on my own without any special hardware?

Comment: I'd try using the design files on the page you link to.  Every file you need is there.  I don't know what you mean by "without any special hardware"

Comment: First determine your time requirements - USB is very *slow* for this, as it was designed to move large amounts of data, not to move small amounts frequently.

Comment: you can just use an ardunio uno and parse commands from the serial port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FTDI USB controller is by far the easiest. Otherwise you need to have a microcontroller with USB peripheral and write firmware for it to look like USB peripheral of some sort like serial port to receive commands and set GPIO pins accordingly.

Comment: Pre-written firmware to do this is available for many MCUs, the FTDI parts are essentially those where the firmware is fixed from the factory.

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial.  To understand how USB works see the documents here: [USB.org Document Library](https://www.usb.org/documents).

You need a microcontroller with suitable firmware and a USB interface.

Many IC manufacturers provide example code for this, FTDI chips work in the same way except the code is pre-programmed by the manufacturer and there are off the shelf USB to serial and USB to parallel adaptors you can buy.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Wirekite](https://github.com/manuelbl/Wirekite/wiki) for the Teensy LC and Teensy 3.2 (which I have written). It comes with the required firmware, a C# library for Windows and an Objective-C library for MacOS to control the pins.

It supports digital input and output, analog input, PWM output, I2C and SPI.

No drivers are needed on MacOS and Windows as it use some driverless USB mode (WinUSB and IOUSBLib respectively).